# 'Rare' sorting algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Our algorithm professor gave us a assignment that requires us to choose a **rare** sorting algorithm (e.g. Introsort, Gnomesort, etc.) and do some research about it.
Wikipedia sure has a plenty of information about this, but it is still not enough for me to do the research in depth.
So I would like to find a book that include discussions of those rare sorting algorithms, since most of the textbooks (like CLRS, the one I am using) only discuss about some basic sorting algorithms (e.g. Bubble Sort, Merge Sort, Insertion Sort.).
Is there a book or website that contains a good amount of those information?
Thanks!

Comment: Internet is full of information and it's the best book ever, if you know how to use it. In this case, you just need some names for such algorithms. And as you say, wikipedia gives you this. The only thing that left - google it and good luck.

Comment: Well there's always: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort

Comment: Yes, I know there are lots of info on the Net. But what I would like to see is a step-by-step and more comprehensive discussion about the specific algorithm like textbooks did. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I will try to search for more info on the Net.

Answer (score 11):

Well, a very interesting "rare" sorting algorithm in Smoothsort by Edsger Dijkstra. On paper it is almost a perfect sort:

```
O(n) best
O(n log n) average
O(n log n) worst
O(1) memory

n comparisons, 0 swaps when input is sorted
```

It is so rare due to it's complex nature (which makes it hard to optimize).

You can read the paper written by Dijkstra himself here: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd07xx/EWD796a.PDF

And here is the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort) and [a very extensive article about smoothsort](http://www.keithschwarz.com/smoothsort/) (by Keith Schwarz).

Comment: Thanks for this "rare" sorting algorithm, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) sort is O(N log^2(N)) (slightly asymptotically slower than the likes of quicksort), but it is parallellizable, with a highly regular structure.  This lets you use SIMD vector instruction sets like SSE -- providing a constant-factor boost which makes it an interesting option for "bottom-level" sorts (instead of the more commonly used insertion sort).

Comment: Thanks! I will choose Bitonic Sort since most of you recommended it.

Answer (score 1):

One of a sorting which may be you say Rare Sorting, is [timsorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), It works great in arrays which are have sorted parts, best case is O(n), and worst and average case is O(n log n).

Another fast way of sorting is [bitonic sorting](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/bitonic/bitonicen.htm), which is base of nearly all parallel sorting algorithms. you can find thousands of papers about in the web, also some books like [Parallel algorithm of Quinn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070510717) you can find extended discussion on it, and related variations of this algorithm.

Also [Art of computer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) volume 3 has good discussion on sorting strategies.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Papers should have a lot of resources.